# Query by time range in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Need to perform a query on a database mongodb resulting in a set of results by time range. I'm using pymongo. My query is as follows:

```
query = {"$and": [
                     {"id_node": id_node}
                     {"port": port},
                     {"datetime": {"$gte": self.hourBegin}}
                     {"datetime": {"$lte": self.now}}
                     ]}
listResults = db.mycollection.find (query)
```

I also tried this way:

```
query = {"id_node": int(id_node)
                     "port": port,
                     "datetime": {"$gte": self.hourBegin, "$lte": self.now}}
listResults = db.mycollection.find (query)
```

But the result is always empty. Tested directly in mongodb but the result is empty. I'm sure the data exists in the database with a time range that I'm researching.

A list of possible results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c6e7b9914c35266128"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A1", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:04Z"), "valor" : "22.00", "sensor" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c6e7b9914c35266129"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A0", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:04Z"), "valor" : "0", "sensor" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c6e7b9914c3526612c"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A1", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:06Z"), "valor" : "22.00", "sensor" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c6e7b9914c3526612d"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A0", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:06Z"), "valor" : "0", "sensor" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c7e7b9914c35266130"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A1", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:08Z"), "valor" : "22.00", "sensor" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c7e7b9914c35266131"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A0", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:08Z"), "valor" : "0", "sensor" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c7e7b9914c35266134"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A1", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:10Z"), "valor" : "22.00", "sensor" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c7e7b9914c35266135"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A0", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:10Z"), "valor" : "0", "sensor" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c7e7b9914c35266138"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A1", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:12Z"), "valor" : "22.00", "sensor" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543618c7e7b9914c35266139"), "lab" : "2", "port" : "A0", "id_node" : 1, "datetime" : ISODate("2014-09-26T18:28:12Z"), "valor" : "0", "sensor" : "1" }
```

Comment: remove the space in your query operator.  Use `$gte` instead of `$ gte`.  Same for `$lte`.

Comment: also use the second variant of the query, but your query object is not valid.  The `id_no` field is missing a `:`.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sample doc you expect to be included in the results?

Comment: Ok, i did, add the sample doc.

Comment: What is type of `self.hourBegin` and `self.now`? how do they look?

Comment: are of type datetime.datetime, are similar to: datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 24, 7, 50, 6, 559897)

Comment: are similar t: datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 24, 7, 50, 6, 559897)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I visit http://www.querymongo.com/, and then created a query as if it were in MySQL, then had to return one mongodb query. like this:

```
#MySQL Query
SELECT * FROM inoshare WHERE id_nome = 1 AND port = 1 AND datetime > 'hourBegin' AND datetime <= 'NOW()';
```

And the return:

```
db.inoshare.find({
"id_nome": 1,
"port": 1,
"datetime": {
    "$gt": "hourBegin",
    "$lte": "NOW()"
}
});
```

Then replace 'hourBegin' and 'NOW ()' for variables.
Thank's for all.